# Protect settings.xml in non-db CMS

Tags: php, xml, .htaccess

My system doesn't use mySQL or smth like that. Just files. I have special folder with .htaccess (deny from all). Where I store my settings, admin's password(md5) etc. But in case if hacker get an access to this folder XML files could be easily read.

Thus my questions: 
1) Does .htaccess file with `deny from all` provide enough protection?
2) Is there any built-in PHP function to encrypt files?

Comment: I would suggest storing sensitve stuff outside the document root

Comment: Question is why you store your internal files at a location that is obviously published by your http server. Certainly they would be better protected if stored in some location in the file system that cannot be reached by an http request _at all_, so _outside_ your document root.

Comment: About the encryption: no clear statement is possible here, but the approach in itself is questionable: it is the attempt to cure a symptom instead of the cause.

Answer (score 0):

1. .htaccess is insufficient to protect files, put local data outside http access, generally in a directory above the HTML directory.
2. There is encryption available in PHP but that just moved the problem to protecting the key although it does increase the work factor and that is basically security is about.

If you do choose to use encryption do not use mcrypt, it is abandonware and does not support standard padding. Instead use a library such as [RNCryptor-php](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-php) or [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) which provided a complete encryption solution.

Note: Some people, when confronted with a security problem, think 
“I know, I'll use encryption.”  Now they have two problems.